# Cannot read property $loading of undefined when using Jest with Nuxt component

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

When I try to test one of my components using nuxt and jest, I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property '$loading' of undefined
```

This is being caused by the following line of code in my component

```
this.$nuxt.$loading.start()
```

How do I prevent this error from occurring when running the test on my component?

The test file looks like this:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Converter from '@/components/Converter.vue'

describe('Converter', () => {
  test('is a Vue instance', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Converter)
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

Comment: you could just mock this

Comment: Jest is mounting your component without Nuxt additional instance properties. you need to mock this. You can do it locally, while mounting component, or you can create global mock if you use it lot (but I dont think so). Mocking is well described in vue-test-utils docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The solution is to mock nuxt like this:

```
const wrapper = mount(Converter, {
  mocks: {
    $nuxt: {
      $loading: {
        start: () => {}
      }
    }
  }
})
```